# MySQL cannot recognize Korean characters

Tags: php, mysql, encode

I need to insert korean text to my database which is coming by url get request. However, inserted values are not recognized in MySQL. Please, need quick instruction. Thanks.

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'ko_KR.utf8');
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");    
mb_http_output('utf-8');   

$p_text = rawurldecode($_GET["text"]);
```

Comment: Make sure your encoding is correct for the tables and connection.

Answer (score 5):

Right after your mysql connection make this query

```
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
```

or

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
```

also make sure that your fields have `utf8_general_ci` collation

Comment: Thank you dude. I did exactly what you said and it worked! :)

Comment: Is there any way to write the characters in normilized method. Now it writes the charset also English letters in fullwidth utf8 which means there is difficulty in comparison after it inserted in the database table.

Comment: dude you're a life saver. I've been doing all sorts of stuff to try to get PHP to display Korean from MySQL properly. This finally worked!!!